# Queue Implementation Trouble C

Tags: c, queue, fifo

I'm having issues implementing a FIFO queue in C that acts as a circular buffer.. I have only managed to write an enqueue method so far and I'm having problems with the output. It doesn't display what it should and I'm not sure where the problem lies.

The code is as follows:

```
struct queue                                                                   
{                                                                              
    int array[30];                                                             
    int *front; //pointer to front of queue                                    
    int *rear;  //pointer to rear of queue                                     

    int count; //counts number of elements in queue                            
};                                                                             

//initialising a queue                                                         
struct queue *init_Queue(){                                                    

    struct queue * q = malloc(sizeof (q));                                     

    q->count=0;                                                                

    q->front=q->array;                                                         
    q->rear=q->array;                                                          

    return q;                                                                  
}                                                                              

int isFull(struct queue *q){                                                   

    if(q->count==30){                                                          
        printf("\n Buffer is full!");                                          
        return 1;                                                              

    }                                                                          

    return 0;                                                                  
}                                                                              

int isEmpty(struct queue *q){                                                  

    if(q->count==0){                                                           
        printf("\n Buffer is empty!");                                         
        return 1;                                                              
    }                                                                          
    return 0;                                                                  
}                                                                              

int enqueue(struct queue * q,int i){                                           

    if(isFull(q)){                                                             
        return 0;                                                              
    }                                                                          

    if(isEmpty(q)){                                                            
        q->front+1;                                                            
    }                                                                          

    int k=*(q->rear)+1;                                                        
    printf("\n %d",k);                                                         

    q->array[k]=i;                                                             

    q->rear+1;                                                                 

    printf("\n Enqueue success!");                                             
    q->count++;                                                                

    return 1;                                                                  
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)                                                 
{                                                                              
    int i=10;                                                                  
    int k=12;                                                                  

    struct queue *q=init_Queue();                                              

    enqueue(q,i);                                                              
    int j= q->count;                                                           
    printf("\n %d",j);                                                         

    printf("\n %d",q->array[0]);                                               
    printf("\n %d",q->rear);                                                   

    enqueue(q,k);                                                              
    int z= q->count;                                                           
    printf("\n %d", z);                                                        
    printf("\n %d", q->array[1]);                                              
    printf("\n %d",q->rear);                                                   

    free(q);                                                                   
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Buffer is empty!
1 
Enqueue success!
1  <<**value of count**
0  << **value stored in array[0]...it should say 10**
1070400  << **q->rear...should be pointing to 10?**
1  
Enqueue success!
2  **<<value of count**
12  **<<value stored in array[1]**
1070400 **<< q-rear...should be incremented and pointing to 12?**
 Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: As a side note, `%p` should be used to printf pointers.

Comment: Step through the `enqueue` function line by line in a debugger to see what happens and what all pointers and values are set.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(*q))` !!

Answer (score 0):

```
  q->rear+1;
```

This do nothing

```
   if(isEmpty(q)){                                                            
        q->front+1;                                                            
    }
```

Why ?

My proposition:

```
int enqueue(struct queue * q,int i){                                           

    if(isFull(q)){                                                             
        return 0;                                                              
    }                                                                          

    if(!isEmpty(q)){                                                           
        q->rear++;                                                             
    }                                                                          

    *(q->rear) = i;                                                            



    printf("\n Enqueue success!");                                             
    q->count++;                                                                

    return 1;                                                                  
}
```

remark prefer return 0 on success and another on error like -1